# WSO2 Identity password recovery

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to send the password recovery notification using our own communication framework (The framework sends SMS and Android notification in addition to the email notification) by following the link [Recover with Notification](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Recover+with+Notification).

> Notification.Sending.Internally.Managed=true
>
> This enables the internal email sending module. If false, the email sending data is available to the application via a Web service. Thus the application can send the email using its own email sender.

Can any one please point me to the webservice that can be used to obtain the 'email sending data' as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not aware of any webservice to receiving email sent from the notification module.

However, you can build a custom notification module and add in component/lib/ folder. see the below link for information and sample code

http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/09/07/custom-notification-module-for-account-management-in-wso2-identity-server-wso2is/